# UVM basic structure: what is the new function?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I'm a beginner in design verification.  I wonder why the code below is used in almost every `class`.

```
class uvm_test_top extends uvm_test;
    `uvm_component_utils(uvm_test_top)

     function new (string name, uvm_component parent);
        super.new(name, parent);
     endfunction // ?
```

I want to know what the `new` function is from the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` function is a member of every `class` in SystemVerilog.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 8.4 *Objects (class instance)*

> A class defines a data type. An object is an instance of that class.
> An object is used by first declaring a variable of that class type
> (that holds an object handle) and then creating an object of that
> class (using the **new** function) and assigning it to the variable.

UVM, which is a library of classes, has the `uvm_test` class which is described in the [UVM class documentation](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/index.html), under the COMPONENTS category.  From the class hierarchy, you can see this class is extended from the `uvm_object` class, and all classes so extended must declare the `new` function.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all UVM classes are extended from `uvm_object`. This class constructor has a `string name` argument which is used for messaging and debugging.

`uvm_test` extends from `uvm_component` which extends from `uvm_object`. The constructor of `uvm_component` adds a `uvm_component parent` argument which is used to create the testbench hierarchy. The testbench hierarchy encapsulates reusable pieces of the testbench as well as selectively applying configuration and report settings.